# Should I create a single client to serve all requests?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am using **Google Firestore** for database.

Currently a new client connection is being created for every call.

Should I make a single global client and serve all requests using that single connection?

Comment: It totally depends upon your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use multiple clients if you want to parallelize your requests. Otherwise, just use a single client and avoid unnecessary allocations.